# Modern OpenGL 3.3 with glfw window not displaying anything

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I just get an empty window without any c++ or opengl errors. And the vao method dosen't work. Im also on a 8 year old laptop, so this also may be the cause.

Here's the code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

// shader stuff (do not understand lol)
static unsigned int compile_shader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source) {
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    // ERRORS
    int resoult;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &resoult);
    if (resoult == GL_FALSE) {
        int lenght;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &lenght);
        char* message = (char*)_malloca(lenght * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, lenght, &lenght, message);
        std::cout << "ERROR !!! Failded to compile shader !!! ERROR" << (type == 
GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

return id;
}

static unsigned int create_shader(const std::string& vertex_shader, const std::string& 
fragment_shader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = compile_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader);
    unsigned int fs = compile_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment_shader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    // Initializing GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Error with glew :((((((" << std::endl;

    // buffer for the triangle
    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.0f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    unsigned int vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, (void*)0);

    std::string vertex =
        "#version 330 core \n"
        "layout(location = 0 ) in vec4 position;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";
    std::string fragment =
        "#version 330 core \n"
        "layout(location = 0 ) out vec4 color;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";
    unsigned int shader =  create_shader(vertex, fragment);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // making a triangle 
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that nowhere in the code shown do you request `OpenGL` version 3.3.  You're probably getting a default 2.1 context or similar in which case a lot of your `OpenGL` function calls are simply invalid.  Rather than relying on youtube videos you'd be better off using a [good tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/).

Comment: Does `glGetError()` return any error?

Comment: no, its no errors, but dosen't display anything

Comment: What is the output of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`?

Comment: Your primitive is not a triangle, but just a line. If the 3 vertices are on a line, a triangle primitive will not render at all. Try `float positions[6] = {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f };`

Comment: thx, it worked, i didn't notice that at all